# Loading resources onCreate casusing java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Tags: android, exception, out-of-memory, android-resources, android-drawable

I am adding some resources onCreate, it works fine on Android 2.2 to 2.3.x but crashes on 4.0+ below is the code snippet

**I have placed all the resources in drawable-mdpi, can that be issue?**

```
private List<Drawable> drawables;
private void getDrawablesList() {

    drawables = new ArrayList<Drawable>();
    for(int i=0; i<26; i++)
        drawables.add(getResources().getDrawable(Utility.getImageIDofGalleryAlphabets(i)));

}
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.gallery);

    getDrawablesList();
    setupUI();
}
```

i get exception in getDrawablesList following line

```
drawables.add(getResources().getDrawable(Utility.getImageIDofGalleryAlphabets(i)));
```

Below is the crash log:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
    at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:605)
    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:551)
    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:437)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.finishDecode(BitmapFactory.java:524)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:499)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:351)
    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:773)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1937)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:664)
    at com.rdx.gallery.GalleryDemoActivity.getDrawablesList(GalleryDemoActivity.java:180)
    at com.rdx.gallery.GalleryDemoActivity.onCreate(GalleryDemoActivity.java:65)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4635)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1970)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2031)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:126)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1166)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4486)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-01 08:31:28.894: I/Process(11767): Sending signal. PID: 11767 SIG: 9
04-01 08:31:28.894: E/AndroidRuntime(11767): Handle UnCaght exceptions. KILLING PID: 11767
```

I know I am loading 26 resources in beginning. The total size of 26 images = 2.57 MB, which I donot think is too large..

What is going wrong? Please share your views

Comment: Since you get OOM errors, surely that is too much. Read through http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Comment: it is hardly 2.5 MB, 200 KB each file...but why it gives out of memory on 4.0??? why not on other devices with lower OS?

Comment: Dude, the crash tells you it is an OOM crash. Then look into how you load your pictures, how large they are and such. I got an app with several low end phones never gets OOM where flagship Sony phones does. It just something you should fix or look into another way of displaying what you want to display.

Comment: @DavidOlsson this is the thing bugging me.. why is it so that low end phone are able to load 26 images 200 KB each very easily, but high end devices like kindle, and other running on 4.0+ above just says OOM..

Answer (score 1):

While it may be only 2.5M to you, Android will scale your resources depending on the pixel density and display size of your device.  It may turn out to be more, once loaded and ready for  use.  Additionally, some devices just don't have lots of memory. You might have only 16M on some devices, and you're sharing that space with Android as well as any other app that may be running in the background. My guess is that your 4.0 device is using more memory for Android than the 2.x device and you're running out of memory earlier.

If you really need all of these images, perhaps you can architect a solution that loads only what is needed at the time, and releases those it doesn't need.  Pain in the butt, but memory is pretty limited on these devices